# Flutter Micro Command

Tags: flutter, command

Is there anyway in flutter by which I can store command in string and then execute.

Like,
`cmdStr = "print('11111111')"`

And then execute this String.

Is there anyway like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can store it inside function then execute it :

```
void main() {
executeString();
}


void executeString() {
  var storedString = "11111111";
  print(storedString);
}
```

Comment: I dont want it to be predefined. It will be from server and changable.